# Can I gain the bonuses from Clever/Rapid Shot when I make a ranged basic attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger

Consider the level 5 ranger daily power Flying Steel:

> **Flying Steel**
>   ...
>   Effect: Until the end of the encounter, if the target ends its turn without cover from you, you can make a ranged basic attack with a weapon against the target as an immediate reaction. This effect also ends if the target has cover from you at the end of any of your turns.

If I were to take the Archery Mastery feat and gain Rapid Shot or Clever Shot, can I gain the effect for the ranged basic attack?

> Effect: You make a ranged basic attack with a weapon against each creature in or adjacent to a square within the attack's range. You take a −2 penalty to the attack rolls.

I'm about 90% sure that I can't do that, although the effect does say: make a ranged basic attack.

Comment: Your question as stated is fine; but the additional questions you ask at the end 1) should be part of a different question and 2) probably aren't a good fit for the SE format unless you have very specific guidelines

Comment: Ok, I will post a seprete question later that corresponds acordingly with specific guidelines! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**No**. Rapid Shot/Clever Shot are actions that happen to have you make a basic attack; they are not basic attacks.

Comment: Thank you that is what I assumed! I was thinking of getting Adamant Arrow style feat, but that would require me to swap out some of my multi-hit powers. Are there other ways of replacing my ranged basic attacks?